# Code runs unnecessarily when using ItemChange event

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this macro to create an event in my "log" calendar from an email if marked/flagged "today". My problem is the macro is creating the same event three times.

```
Public WithEvents OlItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
   Set OlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"). _
        GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub OlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem


If Item.IsMarkedAsTask = oIMarkToday Then

Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objApp = Application


  ' Subfolder named 'Log' under calendar
Set calFolder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Log")
Set olAppt = calFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
With olAppt
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        '.Attachments.Add Item
        .Body = Item.Body
        .Start = Now + 2
        .End = Now + 2.08
        .ReminderSet = False
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .Save
        '.Display 'show to add notes
End With
Set objApp = Nothing
Set Ns = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will run every time an item is changed. Set your own custom property (`Item.UserProperties.Add` / `Item.Save`) to mark it as processed and check for that property (`Item.UserProperties.Find`) along with the `Item.IsMarkedAsTask = oIMarkToday` check before creating a new item.

```
Private Sub OlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objProp As Outlook.UserProperty

set objProp = Item.UserProperties.Find("ProcessedByMe")

If (Item.IsMarkedAsTask) And (objProp Is Nothing) Then

  'mark the original item as processed
  set  objProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("ProcessedByMe", olYesNo)
  objProp.Value = true
  Item.Savwe

  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set objApp = Application

   ' Subfolder named 'Log' under calendar
  Set calFolder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Log")
  Set olAppt = calFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
  With olAppt
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        '.Attachments.Add Item
        .Body = Item.Body
        .Start = Now + 2
        .End = Now + 2.08
        .ReminderSet = False
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .Save
        '.Display 'show to add notes
  End With
  Set objApp = Nothing
  Set Ns = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought something similar is happening during the run. I am not a VBA expert I simply merged to macro available on the internet to make this work... Could you show me how should look this 4 custom property in my code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update, it solved the problem (so it's create only one event), however for some reason it only (but not always) works if I flag the mail, mark as done, and clear the flag. If I simply mark an email as today, nothings happening.

Comment: It also create event for every new incoming email, that is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: When you step through he code, is "Item.IsMarkedAsTask = oIMarkToday" actually satisfied for the incoming emails?

Comment: Yes, so it creates the event

Comment: IsMarkedAsTask is a Boolean property, not one of the OlMarkInterval enums. Your check must be: If (Item.IsMarkedAsTask) And (objProp Is Nothing) Then

Comment: Is there a way to identify the triggering change for the other log entries? I'm facing a similar issue whereby the send/receive function is pushing a change. What property of the mail Item is changed when updates to an item are transmitted back to the server?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Any property can potentially change.