# Copying mail in Items_ItemChange generates three copies

Tags: vba, outlook

My goal is that when I assign a specific category to a mail in a specific mailbox inbox folder, the mail is copied to a specific subfolder and it is saved to an external folder.

The following code saves the mail in the external folder, but it gets copied three times in the inbox subfolder.

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.Folder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.folders("Mailbox_Name").folders("Inbox")
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olInbox  As Outlook.Folder
    Dim ItemCopy As MailItem
    Dim Category As String
    Category = "Test_category"
    Dim ExternalFolder As String
    ExternalFolder = "C:\MyEmails\"
    
    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNameSpace.folders("Mailbox_Name").folders("Inbox")
    Set olFolder = olInbox.folders("Copy")

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item

        If Item.Categories = Category Then
            Set ItemCopy = Item.Copy ' Copy Categorized item
             ItemCopy.Move olFolder ' Move Copied item
             FileName = ExternalFolder & Replace(Replace(Replace(Item.Subject, ":", ""), "/", ""), "\", "") & ".msg" 'This creates the file name for the external folder
            Item.SaveAs FileName, olMSG 'This saves the mail item as a msg file in the external folder
        End If

        Set Item = Nothing
        Set ItemCopy = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook Item Change duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689902/outlook-item-change-duplication)

Comment: See as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136483/code-runs-unnecessarily-when-using-itemchange-event

Comment: @niton thank you for the links. I need further testing, but the solution proposed seems to work so far

Answer (score 0):

`ItemChange` event can and will fire multiple times. Each time it fires, you will end up with a new item in the target folder. You need to come up with a way (setting a custom property on the source email etc.) that prevents copying the same email multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Setting a custom property seems to work so far.

Comment: Just keep in mind that setting a custom property and saving the message will cause `ItemChange` to fire again. Keeping a list of processed items in an external storage (file? Hidden/associated message in the folder?) will help you avoid modifying the very same item you are tracking.

Comment: You are right, there are still some cases in which the ItemChange fires again, so like sometimes I only get one copy, sometimes three again. Could you please give me more information about the list you were mentioning? Is it a generated list? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of setting a property on the item itself, save the entry id of the processed item in an some external location - file, hidden message, etc. When event fires, check if the given entry id is already in that list, if it is, skip it. If not, process it and and the entry id of the message to that external location.